# How can I Deploy software on a randomly choosen available Target machine in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, cicd

We create regular Windows software, not websites. We use CI pipelines to build the software and create our setups.
Now we want to deploy our software on a Target to test our setups if they install well and leave nothing behind on uninstall.

With the CD Release pipeline we want to deploy our software by running the setup on a VMWare VM and revert to a clean snapshot every run. But I am a bit confused about the Deployment Groups and Deployment Pools. Actually I would like to get an available target (or agent) from a pool of agents, **just as with a CI pipeline Agent pool**. But the behavior of Targets in a Deployment Group is quite different, it starts to deploy on every target in the group instead of just one. I only want to test it once.

It looks like I have to create a Deployment Group for every project and in every DG only one Target machine? This means that if several CI builds are running on different Agents from the Agent pool, they will all have to wait for their dedicated Target Machine in their dedicated Deployment Group?

How can I get an available Target machine randomly chosen from a pool of machines in a Release pipeline to Deploy our software on? Or is the [ARM Template deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=azure-devops#deploytask) of any use to us?

Comment: I hoped I had found a solution with a counter and tags. But it is not possible to change tags at runtime.